# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 can't connect to IBM DB2 database using ibm_db2 client

Tags: php, symfony, db2, doctrine-orm

I'm having an issue with Doctrine2 that seems like a bug but I can't find anyone else on Google with the same problem. I'm hoping somewhere here has experienced this problem and knows how to solve it.

Basically I'm trying to connect to a DB2 database. I prefer to use the ibm_db2 client as it's supposed to be better and faster (than PDO_IBM or PDO_ODBC). I've installed the client and tested it. Everything seems to work there. But when I use Doctrine I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: protocol in
...[my folders].../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/
IBMDB2/DB2Driver.php line 54
```

So in that file it's looking for `$params['protocol']` which seems to have no defaults. So in config.yml I tried this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        protocol: TCPIP
```

But when I do that it complains that `protocol` is an undefined configuration option (and looking through the DependencyInjection stuff it doesn't appear anywhere in there.)

However: if I hard-code TCPIP into the Driver file where the error occurs ... it all works. This is undesirable since it involves changing the vendor supplied file. Has anyone found a way to properly specify the protocol in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you're going to run into licensing issues using ibm_db2 [as noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645605/connecting-to-remote-db2-on-i5-os-through-a-php-client-on-a-windows-machine-usin). PDO or ODBC are going to be your only free ways to go. IBM requires DB Connect to use ibm_db2 db2_connect() stuff.