# Connecting to remote DB2 on i5/os through a php client on a windows machine using pdo_ibm or ibm_db2 php extensions

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, db2, ibm-midrange

I want to use Doctrine2 ORM in my php application.

For DB2, Doctrine2 supports only pdo_ibm and ibm_db2 drivers.

I installed a local instance of DB2 (DB2 Express-C) and conneceted with pdo_ibm and ibm_db2 successfully and even using the local db2 instance my doctrine2 installation works fine and is functional,

but my real aim is to connect to a remote DB2 instance running on a i5/os. Remote connections to this (remote) DB2 works only using odbc and PDO_ODBC but fails with pdo_ibm and ibm_db2 resulting in the following error:

> Could not connect SQLSTATE=42968, SQLDriverConnect: -1598 [IBM][CLI
>   Driver] SQL1598N An attempt to connect to the database server failed
>   because of a licensing problem. SQLSTATE=42968

Comment: I don't want to use the very expensive DB2 Connect to do this. Is there a easy and cheap/free way to accomplish the task or get DB2 Connect free

Comment: IBM allows remote connections to DB2 on i through a free JDBC driver, why not provide such flexibility with other platforms

Comment: I connect to DB2 for i using the free driver from IBM (http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/linux_resources.html) - however I don't use Doctrine and my servers all run Linux (Ubuntu). So there is definitely a free option out there (and it's quite easy to set up).

Comment: That must be an ODBC driver as I have mentioned in the description of my question that ODBC driver works fine but I need the pdo_ibm or ibm_db2 php drivers to function when accessing DB2 on System i (i5/os) remotely

Comment: It is mentioned here for pdo_ibm (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.php) : The DB2 Client v9.1 also supports access to DB2 UDB for i5 and DB2 UDB for z/OS servers using the separately purchased » DB2 Connect product.

Comment: It is mentioned here for ibm_db2 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.requirements.php) : To connect to IBM DB2 Universal Database for z/OS or iSeries, you also require IBM DB2 Connect or the equivalent DRDA gateway software.

Comment: It would appear your choices are to either pay for the DB2 Connect software OR use the free Linux driver and (possibly) a different framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Doctrine, I use my own wrapper to swap on the database of my choice :

On Zend Server for Windows : I can use IBM DB2 for Windows with PDO and the extension ibm_db2, or I can use IBM DB2 for i5 with PDO and the "System i ODBC Driver" (provided with "System i Navigator" software).

On Zend Server for IBM i : I swap on the "ibm_db2" connector (and db2_connect).

You'll find the source code and the documentation of my project here :
http://gregphplab.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/2-MacaronDB.html
You can reuse it, or just take the idea. 
Sorry but the documentation is only in french for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine used to connect the function `db2_connect`, but for i5 can connect using `obdc_connect`. Do tests and see the results. `db2_connect` is also available with PECL libraries